# How to integrate neo4j-ogm with unmanaged extension?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to find some example or demo "How to integrate OGM with unmanaged extension" but not able to find any good example.

I tried to use the restapi as unmanaged extension and individually its working fine but   OGM have smart object mapping capability and can be achieved by the `Session` and `Session` is obtained from a
`SessionFactory`.

```
     private final static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("some.domain");
     sessionFactory .openSession();
```

Now how OGM can be use integrate with Unmanaged Extension ?

Can someone please help me for same.

**Edit 1**

Please check below screen shot[image]

**EDIT 2**

Below is code we wrote

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.extension.OgmPluginInitializer;

public class MyApplicationPluginInitializer extends OgmPluginInitializer {


       public MyApplicationPluginInitializer(String packages) {   

              super(packages);

       }


}
```

Class TopologyExtController

```
@Path("/")
public class TopologyExtController {


       @javax.ws.rs.core.Context 
       public org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session session;

       public TopologyExtController( ) {

       }

       @POST
       @Path("/uiv/topology")
       public Response getTopology(TopologyDescription topology, @javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpHeaders headers) {
              try{                

                     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                     Map convertValue = mapper.convertValue(topology, Map.class);

                     Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();           
                     map.put("topology", convertValue);

                     //OGM session used execute the procedure and return the mapped result to end user.
                     Result query = session.query("call uiv.traversal($topology)",map);             

                     Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterator = query.iterator();
                     if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                           Map<String, Object> next = iterator.next();
                           Object object = next.get("rootNodes");

                           return Response.ok(object).status(200).build();

                     }


              }catch (Exception e)
              {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }             

              return Response.ok("Something went wrong").status(400).build();

       }


}
```

META-INF Entry 
\META-INF\services\org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle

```
-   framework.traversal.ext.config.MyApplicationPluginInitializer
```

But error we are geting

> Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: 2018-11-30 09:47:27.611+0000 ERROR
>   The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource
>   and/or provider classes: Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: SEVERE:
>   Missing dependency for field: public org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session
>   framework.traversal.ext.ogm.controller.TopologyExtController.session
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: 2018-11-30 09:47:27.612+0000 WARN 
>   unavailable Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException Nov 30
>   15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) Nov 30
>   15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) Nov 30
>   15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:665)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:423)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418) Nov 30 15:17:27
>   surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385) Nov 30
>   15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:320)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:152)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:321)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.access$700(AbstractNeoServer.java:102)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:527)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107) Nov
>   30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
>   Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: 2018-11-30 09:47:27.639+0000 ERROR
>   Failed to start Neo4j on 127.0.0.1:7474:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-737fd68@2dde7c07==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false Nov 30 15:17:27 surerest2 neo4j: 2018-11-30 09:47:27.658+0000 INFO 
>   Stopping... Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: 2018-11-30
>   09:47:28.279+0000 INFO  Stopped. Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j:
>   2018-11-30 09:47:28.281+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting
>   Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@6c49db66'
>   was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the
>   attached cause exception "null". Starting Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@6c49db66'
>   was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the
>   attached cause exception "null". Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j:
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed:
>   Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@6c49db66'
>   was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the
>   attached cause exception "null". Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: Caused by:
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@6c49db66'
>   was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the
>   attached cause exception "null". Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107) Nov
>   30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: ... 3 more Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2
>   neo4j: Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-737fd68@2dde7c07==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:686)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:423)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418) Nov 30 15:17:28
>   surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385) Nov 30
>   15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:320)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:152)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:321)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.access$700(AbstractNeoServer.java:102)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:527)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: ... 5 more Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2
>   neo4j: Caused by:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException Nov 30
>   15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) Nov 30
>   15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) Nov 30
>   15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:665)
>   Nov 30 15:17:28 surerest2 neo4j: ... 27 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in general not possible. Neo4j-OGM abstracts all transport modes (Bolt, HTTP, embedded) by using Cypher.

...but if your unmanaged extension works completely separated from your business logic (e.g. no transaction boundaries that also contain Neo4j-OGM calls) you could create a call directly through the (Neo4j-OGM) HTTP-driver:

```
HttpDriver httpDriver = (HttpDriver) sessionFactory.getDriver();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpDriver.executeHttpRequest(new HttpGet("http://somewhere"));
response.getEntity().getContent()....
```

please note that this is just a hack to use the raw connection.

Edit (add information for running **inside** Neo4j):

As described [in the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/) you need to provide your own `OgmPluginInitializer` as you already did. But your implementation/constructor does expect the package to be provided somewhere. The service extension that loads the extension does not know about your package structure so the initializer class should look sth. like

```
public class MyApplicationPluginInitializer extends OgmPluginInitializer {
   public MyApplicationPluginInitializer() {   
          super("Your package to scan");
   }
}
```

As a warning: The API used to provide this feature is deprecated in Neo4j 3.5. and could be removed in upcoming versions. As a consequent this feature might get also a refactoring or deleting depending on the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i need a OGM  Session in my unmanaged extension ,is this possible ?

Comment: Using it in an unmanaged extension on the server side is not a good idea. If you get all dependencies in the extension it might be theoretical possible to pass the GraphDatabaseService into an EmbeddedDriver instance but you will loose all benefits of having a direct access to the database and, most of all, you have also to bring your whole domain as a library into the extension.

Comment: Please have a look this [link](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/
https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:configuration:driver:embedded:unmanaged). We are trying this approach but we are not able to make it work ?

Comment: OGM we are using here to Map the Domain entities because Extension dont know anything about Mapping .

Comment: I added code we tried and exception we are getting,Need your help. Thanks

Comment: Isn't the problem based on the fact that you are not passing the actual packages in the `MyApplicationPluginInitializer`? Please look at the documentation again, it says that you have to set your own packages in the constructor. The service extension does not know how to instantiate your plugin initializer.

Comment: May be I am missing something from your comment,but is this possible for you to share some code or example.

Comment: Can you tell me which feature you are going to remove OGM or unmanaged extension or OgmPluginInitializer?

Comment: Looking at this documentation https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/http-server-extensions/#intro-unmanaged-extensions and checking the Neo4j class Neo4j-OGM depends on, which is deprecated in 3.5, the SessionFactory has to get created in the extension's constructor by hand (example in the docs).

Comment: Thanks for your help will check it this weekend and ask more questions if any doubt .